# Will the voting fraud detection algorithm detect this?

Tags: support, down-votes

A few hours ago I got downvoted on all my questions and only questions. Is it because downvoting question is now free?

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/2567/pierre-303?tab=reputation

Comment: Wouldn't that need a voting vendetta detection system?

Comment: I was thinking about that today, and concluded that after all, if the user browser trough my profile, clicked on my questions and liked none of them, he has the right to downvote them isn't? The real problem is: how do you know it's sincere or not?

Comment: It's kind of you to give someone the benefit of the doubt but you've got the highest rep on here. If someone dislikes everything you've asked they're either a complete idiot or it's a vendetta...

Answer (score 1):

Down-votes on questions have been free for a number of weeks now, so it *could* be that someone's just discovered this.

The vote fraud scripts will detect if one person has voted (either way) on more than N posts in less than T time. I don't know the exact numbers here.

So if that's the case you'll get the points back tomorrow.

If you don't - well just move on. Down-votes happen. If the questions are otherwise OK they'll gain more up-votes in the future.

Comment: Thanks. I have no problem with reputation loss, I was more concerned by the potentially new behavior.

Comment: @Pierre - I haven't notice rampant down-voting on any site. I think it has increased (though you'd need a dev to confirm this) as certainly I have been a little more free with down-votes that I was in the past, but not by a massive amount.

Comment: Thanks. I think it's a good thing. IMHO, down voting answers should be free too.